# Decoding JSON with invalid characters

Tags: python, json, encoding

I have a service that is receiving data from an outside service (through a redis list used as a queue). The data is just a flat JSON-encoded dictionary, an example may look like this:

```
{
  "type": "visit",
  "referer": "http://www.google.com/",
  "session_referer": "http://www.google.com/\x0e",
  "uuid": "48e8ea41-420d-021c-be16-7ac5b7c6fb97",
  "user_ip": "1.2.3.4",
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36",
  "user_locale": "en_US",
}
```

The problem is that, as you can see in the above example, sometimes the referrer or session_referrer has invalid data (that can't be decoded using any of the encodings I expect such as UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, etc.).

My issue is that I can't access any of the other data. I can live with the fact that the referrer is messed up, but I still need the other data. Is there any way to do a "raw" decode without turning the data into any specific encoding and then letting me handle it from there?

Comment: Try overriding `json.JSONDecoder` class.

Comment: Is this a 'raw' dump? Is the `\x0e` text *one* character and this is the Python escape sequence, or is it *4* characters (`'\'`, `'x'`, `'0'`, `'e'`). Are these mucked up bytes always at the end of the string, or also in the middle? Is your JSON always formatted across multiple lines?

Comment: Also, is that final comma really there, or is that just a side-effect of an edit to the data before posting it?

Answer (score 2):

Given a text file containing your JSON-like "string" with

1. a hex `0E` byte in the "session_referer" value, and
2. a spurious comma following the last key/value pair:

[image: npp.png]

the following Python code removes the troublesome values ...

```python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import json
import re

# retrieve the JSON data into a string
f = open(r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\jsonData.txt', 'r')
s = f.read()
f.close()
print '~> raw JSON string'
print s
print

# remove "characters" below \x20 except \n
s = re.sub(r'[\000-\011\013-\037]', '', s)
# remove (extraneous) last comma
s = re.sub(',\n}$', '\n}', s)
print '~> tweaked JSON string'
print s
print

# decode tweaked JSON string
j = json.loads(s)

# see what we got
print '~> decoded result "pretty printed"'
print json.dumps(j, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
print

# extract just one element
print '~> print just j["user_ip"]'
print j["user_ip"]
```

... and produces the following results in the Python IDLE shell:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
~> raw JSON string
{
  "type": "visit",
  "referer": "http://www.google.com/",
  "session_referer": "http://www.google.com/♫",
  "uuid": "48e8ea41-420d-021c-be16-7ac5b7c6fb97",
  "user_ip": "1.2.3.4",
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36",
  "user_locale": "en_US",
}

~> tweaked JSON string
{
  "type": "visit",
  "referer": "http://www.google.com/",
  "session_referer": "http://www.google.com/",
  "uuid": "48e8ea41-420d-021c-be16-7ac5b7c6fb97",
  "user_ip": "1.2.3.4",
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36",
  "user_locale": "en_US"
}

~> decoded result "pretty printed"
{
    "referer": "http://www.google.com/",
    "session_referer": "http://www.google.com/",
    "type": "visit",
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36",
    "user_ip": "1.2.3.4",
    "user_locale": "en_US",
    "uuid": "48e8ea41-420d-021c-be16-7ac5b7c6fb97"
}

~> print just j["user_ip"]
1.2.3.4
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try by setting strict = false which allows control characters within string.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html